# How to save only specific iptables chains?

Tags: iptables, iptables-persistent

I need to configure iptables on a linux machine with running docker containers. If I save iptables rules with `iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4`, rules from all chains will be written to file.

But I want to save only INPUT, OUTPUT and DOCKER-USER chains, and don't want chains DOCKER, DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1, etc to be saved, since they contain rules added by docker automatically, which will be irrelevant after reboot.

As far as I know, `iptables-save` can save specific tables, but not specific chains.

Currently I consider to combine `iptables-save` with `grep` to cut rules from unwanted chains. Is there any better way to achieve same result?

Comment: Hey, what solution did you find? Thanks!

Comment: @RicarHincapie I save rules with the following command:
iptables-save | grep -e "-A FORWARD" -e "DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE" -e "-A DOCKER " -e "-A POSTROUTING" -e "-A PREROUTING" --invert-match > /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basic `iptables` command with option `-S` (`--list-rules`) to get similar output for a given chain and table, eg:

```
$ sudo iptables -t filter -S OUTPUT
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
...
```

but you will have to repeat this for each table and chain, and perhaps munge the output a little if you want compatibility for `iptables-restore`, for example adding headers per table like `*filter` and changing the default policy `-P` to `:`, and adding a `COMMIT` to each table.